# Error inflating Button

Tags: android, button

I have a layout with a Button on it:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/myapp_new"
    style="@style/header_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@drawable/header_button"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="new" />
```

The style for the button is defined as such:

```
<style name="header_button" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
</style>
```

When I open this Activity on my phone, I receive a crash.  The crash happens during the line that sets the content view:

```
setContentView(R.layout.layout_tags);
```

If I remove the `android:background` parameter, the crash goes away.  I don't understand because the drawable is included in the app and it works fine on other devices, including the emulator.

I will post the error log at the bottom of this thread.

As I said, this crash is only happening on 1 of my devices (I have 2 + emulator).  It is occurring on an older phone running Android 2.2.1, but is not occurring on my emulator (running 2.2) or my newer phone (running 4.1.2).

The biggest difference is my device with the crash has a low screen resolution.  I have no images in the ldpi folder.  I was under the impression that Android would automatically choose the image from the next folder up.  Also, I have lots of other images that load just fine.

I'd really like to release my app into the Google Play store, but this is holding me up.  I worry that this crash will happen on other people's phones even though I can only reproduce it on one device.  Does anyone have any ideas?  I'm lost.

```
11-26 12:03:04.740: E/AndroidRuntime(2800): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-26 12:03:04.740: E/AndroidRuntime(2800): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myapp.app/com.myapp.app.activity.ActivityTags}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #65: Error inflating class android.widget.Button
11-26 12:03:04.740: E/AndroidRuntime(2800):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
11-26 12:03:04.740: E/AndroidRuntime(2800):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
11-26 12:03:04.740: E/AndroidRuntime(2800):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
11-26 12:03:04.740: E/AndroidRuntime(2800):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
11-26 12:03:04.740: E/AndroidRuntime(2800):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-26 12:03:04.740: E/AndroidRuntime(2800):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-26 12:03:04.740: E/AndroidRuntime(2800):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
11-26 12:03:04.740: E/AndroidRuntime(2800):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-26 12:03:04.740: E/AndroidRuntime(2800):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-26 12:03:04.740: E/AndroidRuntime(2800):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
11-26 12:03:04.740: E/AndroidRuntime(2800):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
11-26 12:03:04.740: E/AndroidRuntime(2800):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-26 12:03:04.740: E/AndroidRuntime(2800): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #65: Error inflating class android.widget.Button
11-26 12:03:04.740: E/AndroidRuntime(2800):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:513)
11-26 12:03:04.740: E/AndroidRuntime(2800):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
11-26 12:03:04.740: E/AndroidRuntime(2800):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
11-26 12:03:04.740: E/AndroidRuntime(2800):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618)
11-26 12:03:04.740: E/AndroidRuntime(2800):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:621)
11-26 12:03:04.740: E/AndroidRuntime(2800):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:621)
11-26 12:03:04.740: E/AndroidRuntime(2800):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:621)
11-26 12:03:04.740: E/AndroidRuntime(2800):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:621)
11-26 12:03:04.740: E/AndroidRuntime(2800):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
11-26 12:03:04.740: E/AndroidRuntime(2800):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
11-26 12:03:04.740: E/AndroidRuntime(2800):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
11-26 12:03:04.740: E/AndroidRuntime(2800):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:198)
11-26 12:03:04.740: E/AndroidRuntime(2800):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1647)
11-26 12:03:04.740: E/AndroidRuntime(2800):     at com.myapp.app.activity.ActivityTags.onCreate(ActivityTags.java:75)
11-26 12:03:04.740: E/AndroidRuntime(2800):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
11-26 12:03:04.740: E/AndroidRuntime(2800):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
11-26 12:03:04.740: E/AndroidRuntime(2800):     ... 11 more
11-26 12:03:04.740: E/AndroidRuntime(2800): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
11-26 12:03:04.740: E/AndroidRuntime(2800):     at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:65)
11-26 12:03:04.740: E/AndroidRuntime(2800):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
11-26 12:03:04.740: E/AndroidRuntime(2800):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:446)
11-26 12:03:04.740: E/AndroidRuntime(2800):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:500)
11-26 12:03:04.740: E/AndroidRuntime(2800):     ... 26 more
11-26 12:03:04.740: E/AndroidRuntime(2800): Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
11-26 12:03:04.740: E/AndroidRuntime(2800):     at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable$StateListState.<init>(StateListDrawable.java:255)
11-26 12:03:04.740: E/AndroidRuntime(2800):     at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.<init>(StateListDrawable.java:301)
11-26 12:03:04.740: E/AndroidRuntime(2800):     at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.<init>(StateListDrawable.java:68)
11-26 12:03:04.740: E/AndroidRuntime(2800):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:750)
11-26 12:03:04.740: E/AndroidRuntime(2800):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:729)
11-26 12:03:04.740: E/AndroidRuntime(2800):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1694)
11-26 12:03:04.740: E/AndroidRuntime(2800):     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:581)
11-26 12:03:04.740: E/AndroidRuntime(2800):     at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:160)
11-26 12:03:04.740: E/AndroidRuntime(2800):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:788)
11-26 12:03:04.740: E/AndroidRuntime(2800):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:729)
11-26 12:03:04.740: E/AndroidRuntime(2800):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1694)
11-26 12:03:04.740: E/AndroidRuntime(2800):     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:581)
11-26 12:03:04.740: E/AndroidRuntime(2800):     at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:160)
11-26 12:03:04.740: E/AndroidRuntime(2800):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:788)
11-26 12:03:04.740: E/AndroidRuntime(2800):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:729)
11-26 12:03:04.740: E/AndroidRuntime(2800):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1694)
11-26 12:03:04.740: E/AndroidRuntime(2800):     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:581)
11-26 12:03:04.740: E/AndroidRuntime(2800):     at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:160)
11-26 12:03:04.740: E/AndroidRuntime(2800):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createF
```

Comment: maybe `android:id="@+id/new"` causing problem because new is reserved keyword in java

Comment: Sorry, the id isn't actually "new."  I changed it because it contained the name of my app (ex: myapp_new).  The crash has something to do with setting the background.

Comment: Are you using a StateListDrawable as background? Can you post that too?

Comment: Sounds like your `header_button`  background depends on itself...

Comment: You guys were on to it.  I wasn't paying attention.  I named my button and the pressed version of that button `header_button` and `header_buttonp` respectively.  I also named the StateListDrawable `header_button`.  Curious that it works on other devices (especially an emulator running the same version of Android).  @dmon - post the answer and I will make it correct.  Thanks, guys.

Comment: I guess this only happens on ldpi devices because you do not have resources for it and the resource from the default drawable folder is used then, which is your xml drawable.

Comment: I suppose so.  Another interesting thing is that I had 2 other buttons doing the same thing (the images files were the same name as the StateListDrawable), but there was no crash.

Comment: Done. Also formatted it more like an answer :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `StackOverflowError` exception makes me think that your `header_button` background depends on itself, so it's recursively loading the same file until it dies.

Comment: This was the problem.  My button's image is `header_button.png` and the drawable XML that references it is called `header_button.xml`.  I changed the name of the png and it fixed the issue.

Comment: That's so deep. Nihilist even.